# How to know USB or SATA interface speed (during writing / reading) in real time

Tags: linux, usb, sata, monitoring

I'm working on a real-time system (Linux) and I need to monitor my ports (USB / SATA). And I need to know in command line when a USB key is writing or reading and at which speed ? Now I can know when a device is inserted on my system but not its activity.

I searched on Internet but I've only found how to get the USB key capabalities and a command `hdparm` that doesn't convince me.

Thanks in advance

Alexis

Comment: `iostat` in sysstat?

Comment: I installed the package. I do not see the counters increments (wkB/s) when I'm writing a file on a USB key...